# Remove Bottom Margin

Tags: html, css

How would I remove the bottom space below the red box where the copyright is contained? This is caused from trying to reposition the main content area over the slider.

[Website with issue](http://sosfirstaid.ca/dev/)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `top:0` to your footer style as its picking up a `top:-15px` from another style

```
footer.footer {
    background: #dfdfdf;
    color: #fff;
    top: 0;
    padding-top:0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try this I end up getting a gap above the red footer area. How would I resolve that?

Comment: @CamrinParnell in the same way this was fixed as it think it also has a negative top value set. You should review the rule that has set the top:-15px as it seems to be applied to a lot of elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `footer` class must contain `top: 0`.